# How to display an array updating periodically in a table in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

I have an array of data from an API which I need to display in a React table.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
1:
name: "Station-1"
x: (1433) ['2022-04-05 14:33:00', '2022-04-05 
14:32:00', '2022-04-05 14:31:00', '2022-04-05 
14:27:00', ...]
y: (1433) ['26.1', '26.1', '26.1', '26.1', ...]
2:
name: "Station-2"
x: (1433) ['2022-04-05 14:32:00', '2022-04-05 14:31:00', '2022-04-05 14:30:00', '2022-04-05 14:26:00', ...]
y: (1433) ['25.6', '25.7', 'ERR', '25.6', ...]
3:
name: "Station-3"
x: (1433) ['2022-04-05 14:32:00', '2022-04-05 14:31:00', '2022-04-05 14:30:00', '2022-04-05 14:26:00', ...]`enter code here`
y: (1433) ['25.4', '25.5', '25.5', '25.6', ...]
```

This data updates every minute and I need to display it in a table with the format shown below that also updates whenever new data is fetched.

```
Station/Time            Station-1      Station-2       Station-3
2022-04-05 14:33:00     26.1                            
2022-04-05 14:32:00     26.1            25.6            25.4
2022-04-05 14:31:00     26.1            25.7            25.5
2022-04-05 14:30:00                     ERR             25.5
2022-04-05 14:29:00
2022-04-05 14:28:00
2022-04-05 14:27:00     26.1
2022-04-05 14:26:00                     25.6            25.6
```

**Note:**
I have already fetched the data and it's working. I just need to display it in this table format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect()` with `setInterval()` like so:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    
    yourFetchFunctionHere()
    const interval=setInterval(()=>{
        yourFetchFunctionHere()
     },60000) // <== this is one minute
       
       
     return clearInterval(interval)
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have no problem fetching the data periodically. I just need to display it in a table as shown in the format above.